# Prove duality of multiple zeta values by Extended Double Shuffle Relations

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, zeta-functions

It is easy to prove the duality theorem of multiple zeta values (MZVs) by the integral representation of MZVs. However, how does one prove MZV's duality theorem solely by Finite Double Shuffle Relations (FDS) and Extended Double Shuffle Relations (EDS)? It is conjectured that FDS and EDS relations suffice to give all $\mathbb{Q}$-linear relations among MZVs.

My primary reference comes from this paper: [Derivation and double shuffle relations for multiple zeta values](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1112/S0010437X0500182X/fulltext.pdf).

FDS means $Z(w_1 ⧢ w_2 - w_1*w_2)=0 \;\;\forall w_1,w_2\in \mathfrak{H}^0 $, where $\mathfrak{H}^0$ is the set of admissible words and $Z$ is the evaluation map that maps an admissible word to its corresponding MZV. For example, under the notation of the paper, $Z(xy)=\zeta(2)$, $Z(xxyy)=\zeta(3,1)$, and $Z(xxxy)=\zeta(4)$. Details of this FDS equation are explained in "1. Double shuffle relations (convergent case)" of the paper.

EDS refers to the use of any property described in Theorem 2 of the paper (in "3. EDS relations").

For example, I can prove that $\zeta(4)$ and $\zeta(2,1,1)$ are dual to each other, i.e. $\zeta(4)=\zeta(2,1,1)$ or $Z(xxxy)=Z(xyyy)$. According to Theorem 2(v), $$Z(\text{reg}_⧢(y^m * w_0))=0 \;\;\forall m\geq 1, w_0\in\mathfrak{H}^0$$
Compute $\text{reg}_⧢(y* xxy)$:
$$\text{reg}_⧢(y* xxy)=-xxyy+xxxy-xyxy$$
So $Z(-xxyy+xxxy-xyxy)=0$, or
$$Z(xxxy)=Z(xxyy)+Z(xyxy)$$
On the other hand, compute $\text{reg}_⧢(y* xyy)$:
$$\text{reg}_⧢(y* xyy)=-xyyy+xyxy+xxyy$$
So
$$Z(xyyy)=Z(xyxy)+Z(xxyy)$$
Thus, we get $Z(xxxy)=Z(xyyy)$.
However, for dualties of higher-weight MZVs, such as $\zeta(5)=\zeta(1,1,1,2)$, this kind of computation gets complicated, and I cannot find a systematic approach.